# VBA: How to find the values after a "@" symbol in a string

Tags: string, vba

I am trying to set the letters after a @ symbol to a variable.

For example, `x = @BAL`

I want to set `y  = BAL`

Or `x = @NE`

I want `y = NE`

I am using VBA.

Answer (score 8):

`Split()` in my opinion is the easiest way to do it:

```
Dim myStr As String
myStr = "@BAL"
If InStr(, myStr, "@") > 0 Then '<-- Check for your string to not throw error
    MsgBox Split(myStr, "@")(1)
End If
```

As wisely pointed out by [Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49039453/vba-how-to-find-the-values-after-a-symbol-in-a-string/49039865#comment85085219_49039865), you should check to ensure the string contains the value, which he checks in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49039453/vba-how-to-find-the-values-after-a-symbol-in-a-string/49039865#comment85084285_49039453) by doing: `y = Split(x,"@")(ubound(Split(x,"@"))`. Another way you can do it is using `InStr()`: `If InStr(, x, "@") > 0 Then...`

The `(1)` will take everything *after* the **first instance** of the character you are looking for. If you were to have used `(0)`, then this would have taken everything before the `@`.

---

Similar but different example:

```
Dim myStr As String
myStr = "@BAL@TEST"

MsgBox Split(myStr, "@")(2)
```

The message box would have returned `TEST` because you used `(2)`, and this was the second instance of your `@` character.

---

Then you can even split them into an array:

```
Dim myStr As String, splitArr() As String
myStr = "@BAL@TEST"

splitArr = Split(myStr, "@")   '< -- don't append the collection number this time

MsgBox SplitArr(1)  '< -- This would return "BAL"
MsgBox SplitArr(2)  '< -- This would return "TEST"
```

---

If you are looking for additional reading, here is more from the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/split-function):

> ## [Split Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/split-function)
>
> **Description** Returns a zero-based, one-dimensional array containing a specified number of substrings. **SyntaxSplit**( **expression** [ ,**delimiter** [ ,**limit** [ ,**compare** ]]] ) The **Split** function syntax has thesenamed arguments:
>
> **expression**
>
> > Required. String expression containing substrings and delimiters. If expression is a zero-length string(""), **Split** returns an empty array, that is, an array with no elements and no data.
>
> **delimiter**
>
> > Optional. String character used to identify substring limits. If omitted, the space character (" ") is assumed to be the ***delimiter***. If delimiter is a zero-length string, a single-element array containing the entire ***expression*** string is returned.
>
> **limit**
>
> > Optional. Number of substrings to be returned; -1 indicates that all substrings are returned.
>
> **compare**
>
> > Optional. Numeric value indicating the kind of comparison to use when evaluating substrings. See Settings section for values.

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following to get the substring after the @ symbol.

```
x = "@BAL"

y = Right(x,len(x)-InStr(x,"@"))
```

Where x can be any string, with characters before or after the @ symbol.

Comment: personally I would use MID, less typing `y = Mid(x,InStr(x,"@")+1)`

Comment: I think Right() is more intuitive. Anyway, there are many ways to accomplish this task, it's whichever one makes more sense to you.

Comment: more like`Mid(x, ((InStr(x, "@") -1) And 65535) + 2)` in case `@` is missing

Comment: This works good in an Access Query also like this `y: Right([access_field],Len([access_field])-InStr([access_field],"."))`